# Multiline textbox value split using javascript in Asp.Net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Asp.Net C# Multiline textbox(textbox1) value split after 35 charaters of address & add to textbox(textbox2 - Singleline) again split next 35 charaters & add to textbox(textbox3 - Singleline) again split next 35 charaters & add to textbox(textbox4 - Singleline) again split next 35 charaters & add to textbox(textbox5 - Singleline).
**Note:** While Splitting value after 35 characters make sure if a word is incomplete then add that word in next line like(...31 address  -  here at add position of address is 35 characters so it'll get slipt & gets add to new textbox, but I want that word address in new textbox & from their it should count to 35 charaters like so on.)

I've tried this but didn't work..

```js
function CheckReturns() {

            var txt = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
            var splitResults = txt.value.split("\n");

            if (splitResults[splitResults.length - 1].length < 35) {
                if (splitResults[3].length > 0) {
                    document.getElementById('address4').value = splitResults[3];
                }
                return true;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('address1').value = splitResults[0];
                document.getElementById('address2').value = splitResults[1];
                document.getElementById('address3').value = splitResults[2]; 
                txt.value = txt.value + "\n";
            }
        }
```

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="140" Rows="10" Columns="60"
                onblur="return CheckReturns();" placeholder="Enter Address here.."></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Address1:<asp:TextBox ID="address1" runat="server" Width="220px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
            <br />
            Address2:<asp:TextBox ID="address2" runat="server" Width="220px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
            <br />
            Address3:<asp:TextBox ID="address3" runat="server" Width="220px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
            <br />
            Address4:<asp:TextBox ID="address4" runat="server" Width="220px" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you want this answer written in JS?

Comment: Yes then assign that value to the textboxes.

Comment: I don't think I'd use Split, personally. I'd get one long string, start a loop from 35th character and work backwards to find a space then substring at that place into first textbox, then reduce long string by that and go again, keep doing it another 4 times

Comment: You could use split, if you split on spaces, then repeatedly add words to text boxes as long as you didn't go over 35. If the currently-adding word will take you over 35, move to inserting into the next textbox. If the currently adding word is longer than 35 you'll have to substring it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a JS that implements the logic I discussed in my first comment:

```
let longAddr = "this is a really long address with lots of words longer than 35 characters all over the place and i dont know where it is going to stop it just keeps going so it's like the longest address in the world which is a little bit crazy but there you go";

let addr = ["","","","",""];

for(let i = 0; i < 5 && longAddr.length > 0; i++){

    if(longAddr.length < 35 || i == 4)
    {
        addr[i] = longAddr;
        break;
    }
    
    let cut = 35;
    while(longAddr[cut] !== " " && cut > 0)
        cut--;
    if(cut == 0) //word longer than 35 chars here
      cut = 35;
    
    addr[i] = longAddr.slice(0, cut);
    longAddr = longAddr.slice(cut + 1);
}

console.log(addr);
```

It results in an array that has 5 elements with the string cut up into them. Now all you have to do is put the values in your textboxes